# PC shuts downs completely without warning

Tags: power-supply, shutdown

History:
The PC was running fine and suddenly one day it suddenly shuts down without warning, no Blue screen message nothing.

I investigated more and find out if i on the PC first time of a day it may take you the windows screen and then shuts down suddenly.
If i try it again it may ends up shutting down before windows and sometimes till Boot screen or when we press F1. So it looks like after something/components gets heat up the time till which it on reduces.

Say first 1 minutes, then 20 seconds and then 10 second may.

The PC is a ready made from company called HCL.
Age is 10 years
Had 2 Rams and 2 Hard Disks.

To test it the component is faulty, i used 1 Ram and 1 HD at a time, removed the Ethernet and CD Drive completely, dont have any Video Card, though have a sound card. Think of i applied all combination possible with least hardware

But it didnt worked. All Fans are working fine. Remove the CPU chip clean it and it still shuts down suddenly.

Looks like the PSU is faulty (as per all the articles i found) or may be some Capacitor of Motherboard. Also seeing one of the answer the motherboard beeps too if no RAM is attached, so theoretically it is fine.

But i also dont want to spend money on PSU until fully sured if it is faulty and there is no good technicians nearby as most of the person here just ask you to buy a new motherboard forgot about thinking about capacitors

Tech Details:
2 RAMS, 256 MB (built in) and 512 MB (attached 6 years back)
Pentium 4
Hardisk 5200 RPM and 7200 RPM (the last one is not plugged in for so long)

---

Dont have any power back and the CPU has a hobby of shutting down when power goes off in past.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering about your processor chip.  You said you took the chip out and cleaned it.  Have you done this before? Did you put fresh thermal compound on the chip before putting the heatsink back on?  If you didn't that can cause problems as the heat from the processor may not transfer to the heatsink effectively.

With that in mind if your fans are working like you said and the air flow and the air intakes and outlets are clear of any dust etc. it could be the PSU going faulty but from what you are describing with shorter power-up times each time it does sound like an overheating issue.

The problem is that with a computer 10 years old it could be anything causing the problem.  The processor could be overheating, the motherboard might think the processor is overheating (if it has thermal detection) due to old and faulty components on the motherboard, it could be the PSU getting old and tired.... It sounds like to me that you maybe ought to just go and invest a little more into a new computer.

On the other hand you could go and get a very good PSU on the understanding that it could be used in a new computer that you put together yourself if that doesn't help in your current 10 year old computer.

Comment: This is the first time i removed the processor chip and yes even i thought of getting a very good PSU to create a new PC but i had a plan to revive this and use it for say 2-3 more years and use it for managing source code Subversion/TFS and SQl. Helpful answer though